# Button events inside UIWebView

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiwebview

I want to have a on top of uiwebview, which will scroll out of view as I scroll webview downward. The problem is I am not able to raise/handle the button touchupinside event from the viewcontroller. My guess is webview is eating the event. How can I make the button raise events?
One solution is to have a subview containing the button and then have this and the webview inside a scrollview. However this has its own problems and more so because my webpage has expandable sections inside it.
I am currently adding the button as subview inside documentview of the uiwebview, so it scrolls out of view.

Any help in this regard will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: some sample code would help, theres no reason webview should be "eating" the event if you set things up correctly

Answer (score 0):

It's a WebView, so if you're button is actually on the webpage, just use a simple [Name attribute on the anchor tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_name.asp).

If it's not, and it's a UIButton event you are trying to listen to, chances are you wired something up incorrectly with your IBOutlets and IBActions.  To send a message to a UIWebView to make it scroll, you can send the `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:` message which will call javascript inside your page.  Check out [the docs](http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIWebView/stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:) for details.